# What is the best strategy to survive against mass teaming on Agar.io FFA?

Tags: agar.io

More than once, as I was playing Agar.io (desktop), in the FFA game mode, I starded out well, quickly rose to the top of the leaderboard, and maintained it for a long period of time, only to eventually get teamed against by many of the other leaderboard players.

Here's an example:

I was playing as "【ƤVŦ】㊴ Ŧřŏĵăň" *('[PVT] 39 Trojan')*, and I went to the top of the leaderboard in less than 3 minutes. After about 45 minutes of leading at #1/#2, I started seeing names like 'Kill Trojan', 'Perverttrjdies', and 'killperverttroja'. And many others wanted to help them. It was eventually me fighting everyone.

Here was my strategy: Stay away from viruses, not splitting unless one of my halfs would at least total my entire prior mass {to avoid other players splitting for the bigger half after consuming the smaller one). I also avoided corners, where even smaller people could eat me, because of teaming. I peaked at a little over 11k mass, and was soon after bust 3 times by viruses. I eventually gave all my mass to a tiny player, and left.

[image]

Are there any better strategies to take advantage of the teamed efforts of other players, to grow in mass and maintain a leaderboard giant status? I did not have a teamate, so fast regrouping was impossible.

Comment: If you can't get allies (by throwing them some mass with W) you have to eat them all. There's no answer to this question, there's nothing you can do to prevent the whole server to team up and defeat you. Also there's no win condition in the game, but achieving that I'll consider it as one. So congrats!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone teams and they do this really good, then you have to do something really quick.

Because teamers can farm virus cells and gets **big really fast**. The only way to kill them is to kill them when they are small, but if this doesn't work **you have to stay big everytime**.

You maybe have to **solo team**.
Like split inside virus cell when you have 400 mass and then go into other virus cells, you will see you can eat them because you splitted 16 which is the maximal number to split.

So if you split and you have **16 cells then you can't split anymore**.

So if you are really big **farm viruses**, because the other team **can't see everything what you see** (If they don't have any other stuff, idk)

So if they shoot a virus on you then you are protected. 
At **FFA there is something called Anti-Teaming**, teamers **lose mass each time** (**Also you** but only in a specified amount of mass) so they get smaller. And yes there is something funny to it because at Party mode you can't split for everyone but at FFA you can split to into people you think "I think if I split on him I can't eat him" but there must be a difference.

You can also **split yourself and then feed yourself** so that one of your cells gets bigger so you can split on the team and move really fast, but other cells may want to eat you later too. But you merge in a amount of time.

**If you are big it takes longer to merge!
So smaller cells merges faster than bigger cells!**

You can also feed a cell you don't know, just don't feed him to much maybe you can't eat him later. But if you gave him enough food then you can split on him and move faster.

But if you **feed you lose mass** but **if you split all mass you have is safe**.

So like feeding another **cell** and eating him will make you smaller instead of spliting and then let him eat up everything and **then** eat him will safe your mass.

**Jumbo is famous for his Solo-Teaming, you may watch one of his videos**

Comment: That's a good answer, thanks. I am level 62 now, and follow all the main youtubers. What gets me the worst is in ffa, anti-teaming activates when I eat viruses and self feed, so all my MLG moves end up losing me 5-10k mass. I do know how to popsplit, and reverse a tricksplit/cannonsplit. When I play o am usually end up at the top of the leaderboard for more than an hour, and people start naming themselves with names about killing me, and teaming up to virus / eat me

Comment: It doesn't help that if they virus me, and then the small pieces get eaten, anti-teaming is activated and I shrink very fast.

Comment: Everything I said in my answers has something to do with the video. As I said feeding your self so that one of your cells gets big, and 16 splits so no one can virus split you but you can eat the viruses.

Comment: I've seen that vid. It's pretty good.

Comment: Yes, and if you noticed what he did you will learn how to fight against teamers.

If you feed yourself you get big and bcs of the anti teaming thing the other cell loses mass and you can eat him faster.

Comment: Self feeding makes anti teaming activate on you, too. All the pro solo moves activate anti-teaming. Lol. Most good pro teamers are in party mode, but ya know, there are always a few Rebels out there

Comment: Yeah but you have more changes to survive, because you do a team strategy.

Answer (score -1):

If its a small sized team, try to eat them if your bigger. If ones really big and they're both bigger than you then get away ASAP!

Comment: I do know how to reverse tricksplit, I know how to doublesplit a sloppy splitrun, but when you've been #1 for an hour solo, and everyone starts teaming against you to take you down, it's hard to fight back in an mlg manner without anti teaming mode activating and losing 10k mass